# What is the maximum value of $x^TAx$ subject to $x\in\{\pm1\}^n$?

Tags: optimization, positive-definite, discrete-optimization, non-convex-optimization

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be symmetric and positive definite. What is the following maximum?

$$\max_{x\in\{\pm1\}^n}x^T A x$$

---

My attempt:

if all $a_{ij}\geq 0$, then

\begin{equation}
\max_{x\in\{\pm1\}^n}x^TAx=\sum a_{ij}
\end{equation}

and in this case $x=[1\quad 1\quad\cdots\quad 1]'$ or $x=[-1\quad -1\quad\cdots\quad -1]'$.

if some $a_{ij}<0$, then situation is not clear, but we know that $x^TAx\leq\sum{|a_{ij}|}$.

For example:

\begin{equation}
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
 2 & 3  &  1    \\
 3 & 10 &  -8  \\
 1 & -8  &  17
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\max_{x\in\{\pm1\}^n}x^TAx=49<\sum |a_{ij}|=53
\end{equation}
and in this case $x=[1\quad1\quad-1]'$ or $x=[-1\quad-1\quad1]'$. So idea is to sacrifice $2a_{13}$ since it is smaller than $2a_{23}$ and $2a_{12}$.

Is there any systematic way to tell the maximum of $x^TAx$ for any $n$ if $A$ is given? and if yes how to find $x$ that will give the maximum? Any suggestions are welcome :)

Comment: in the example above, spectral radius of $A$ is 22.265 But maximum is 49. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: so $|x_i|$=1 and $||x||_{\infty}=1$ are similar?

Comment: what I wanted to say is that all elements of $x$ are equal to 1 or -1, so I think I will better stick to $|x_i|=1$

Comment: @Lee and Rodrigo : Both of you are right. Sorry it is my mistake still, precising that $i$ goes from $1$ to  $n$ would not hurt. An alternative way to write is simply $x\in\{-1,1\}^n$

Comment: ok, let me change then

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2126489/339790

Comment: This is known as a Binary Quadratic Problem and is hard. There are some solvers for it, for instance http://www-lipn.univ-paris13.fr/BiqCrunch/ and you can have some success solving a sequence of semidefinite relaxations.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Using the link you have sent, I reformulate my problem to dual problem: \begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \mbox{tr} (\mathrm X)\\ \text{subject to} & \mathrm X - \mathrm M \succeq \mathrm O_n\end{array} where $X$ and $M$ are positive definite matrices and $X$ is diagonal. This link provides some similar problem (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2250901/minimize-trace-of-a-given-that-a-n-is-positive-semi-definite), but since $X$ is diagonal in my case $tr(X)>tr(M)$, if $M$ is non-diagonal. Any suggestions please?

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek thanks for suggestion. I need to get analytical solution. I already have solution using matlab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer, maybe will be useful for someone.

For details go to this paper: http://users.isy.liu.se/en/rt/claal20/Publications/bipartite_consensus.pdf

Here $A$ represents an undirected graph. If $A$ is structurally balanced (condition of structurally balanced given in the paper), then $\max x^TAx = \sum |a_{ij}|$ and we can find at which corner objective function achieves maximum. However, if $A$ is not structurally balanced, $\sum |a_{ij}|$ can never be achieved. In this case, we have to go through all corners numerically to find the maximum.

For example,  $\begin{equation}
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
 2 & 3  &  1    \\
 3 & 10 &  -8  \\
 1 & -8  &  17
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}$ is structurally unbalanced so we can never achieve 53. However, $\begin{equation}
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
 2 & 3  &  -1    \\
 3 & 10 &  -8  \\
 -1 & -8  &  17
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}$ is structurally balanced and for $x=[1\quad 1\quad -1]'$ or $x=[-1\quad -1\quad 1]'$ we can achieve 53.